# ASR9K line default width 0 does not work. Any idea?

Tags: cisco-asr

I was trying to set default terminal width to 0 (or longer than 80) on ASR9K router.

But as seen below, once I logout and login terminal width is changed to 80.

Please advise me what is wrong with me.

```
RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:ASR9K(config)#line default width 0
RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:ASR9K(config)#commit
RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:ASR9K(config)#end
RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:ASR9K#sh terminal
Wed Jun 25 13:33:33.209 UTC
Line "vty0", Location "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", Type "VTY"
Length: 25 lines, Width: 0 columns
Baud rate (TX/RX) is 0, "Empty" Parity, 0 stopbits, 0 databits
Template: default
Capabilities: Timestamp Enabled
Allowed transports are telnet ssh.
RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:ASR9K#exit
Connection to ASR9K closed.
[root@server ~]# ssh ASR9K -l admin
admin@ASR9K's password:
RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:ASR9K#sh terminal
Wed Jun 25 13:34:37.904 UTC
Line "vty0", Location "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", Type "VTY"
Length: 25 lines, Width: 80 columns
Baud rate (TX/RX) is 0, "Empty" Parity, 0 stopbits, 0 databits
Template: default
Capabilities: Timestamp Enabled
Allowed transports are telnet ssh.
```